# Edit comment box script to be dynamic

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook-social-plugins

in order to edit the script of facebook plugin comment box to be dynamic and displays comments related to each post separately, I've added these 2 lines of code into the script :

```
var related = document.getElementById('fb-related');
related.setAttribute("data-href", "articles.aspx?art_id=<%# Request.QueryString["art_id"] %>"); ... (the rest of code) </script>
```

and this is the div where the comment box appear

```
<div id="fb-related" class="fb-comments" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

but nothing happens and the comment box doesn't appear at all ,or appears saying **The comments plugin requires an href parameter.** !! any help please ?

**note that** *I'm using asp.net with C#*

Comment: don't have experience with facebook plugin but have you tried to put the whole url http : //www.... to the data-href and not the relative path only?

Comment: yes ,but also the same error appears to me :/

Comment: Maybe try to put the data-href attribute in CodeBehind on the PageLoad event with C# code so when the page renders the plugin will already have a data-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data-href attribute in CodeBehind on the PageLoad event with C# code so when the page renders the plugin will already have a data-href